# Create controller with service — Get... is not a function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, angularjs-scope, asp.net-boilerplate

In an ASP.NET Boilerplate project, I have the following code:

```
(function () {
    appModule.controller('augustinum.views.kostenstelle.index', [
        '$scope', '$uibModal', 'abp.services.app.kostenstelle',
        function ($scope, kostenstelleService) {
            var vm = this;

            vm.kostenstellen = [];

            vm.getKostenstelle = function () {
                kostenstelleService.getKostenstelle().then(function (result) {
                    vm.kostenstellen = result.items;
                    console.log("Step1" + vm.kostenstellen.length);
                });
            };

            vm.getKostenstelle();   
            console.log("Step2" + vm.kostenstellen.length);
        }
    ]);
})();
```

I have two questions:

1. I get the error:

   > getKostenstelle() is not a function.

   If I replace `kostenstelleService.getKostenstelle()` with `abp.services.app.kostenstelle.getKostenstelle()` the code works — the object list `Kostenstelle` is returned. But I think I lost the scope with this workaround, so what is wrong with the `kostenstelleService`?
2. If the code works (by replacing `kostnestelleService`), I get `2` elements in the array `kostenstelle[]`. At the line with `"Step1"` I get the correct number — `2` elements. But at the line with `"Step2"`, I get `0` elements. Why? And how can I change the code, so the line with `"Step2"` is executed when the array is filled?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1) That's because you forgot to include `$uibModal` in here `function ($scope, kostenstelleService) {` (line 4). Therefore `kostenstelleService` points at `$uibModal` now.

Should be:

```
appModule.controller('augustinum.views.kostenstelle.index', 
    ['$scope', '$uibModal', 'abp.services.app.kostenstelle',
    function ($scope, $uibModal, kostenstelleService) {
```

2) That's because `getKostenstelle()` is an asynchronous operation wrapped in a promise. JavaScript is single threaded, meaning that it goes through each operation one by one and puts async ops in the pending queue so that it doesn't get thread locked.

In your case, what happens is:

1. Execute `vm.getKostenstelle()`

   - Execute `kostenstelleService.getKostenstelle()` and put in pending queue
2. Execute `console.log("Step2" + vm.kostenstellen.length);`

   - At this point `vm.kostenstellen.length` is empty because the async call hasn't finished
3. Async call `kostenstelleService.getKostenstelle()` finishes

   - `.then` block is executed; `vm.kostenstellen` is assigned data and `console.log("Step1" + vm.kostenstellen.length);` displays data